# How can I improve this toggleClass function containing basically repeated logic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `toggleClass` function that basically reverses the classes in an `if..else` depending on whether the state is a delete or reset. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how I can improve this to make it better?

**JS**

```
/**
 * Uses the click events currentTarget as the element and a state string
 * to work out how the required classes should be toggled.
 * 
 * @param $el - jQuery click event
 * @param state - string `reset` or `delete`
 */
toggleClass: function($el, state) {

    console.log('toggleClass', state);

    if(state === 'delete') {
        $el.toggleClass('js-delete-session js-reset-session');
        $el.toggleClass('fa-times fa-undo');
    } else {
        $el.toggleClass('js-reset-session js-delete-session');
        $el.toggleClass('fa-undo fa-times');
    }

},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement to toggle class `js-delete-session` and `js-reset-session` is common in both `if` and `else` block, it can be moved outside of `if else`.

```
toggleClass: function($el, state) {
    // Common to both delete and reset
    $el.toggleClass('js-delete-session js-reset-session');

    if(state === 'delete') {
        $el.toggleClass('fa-times fa-undo');
    } else {
        $el.toggleClass('fa-undo fa-times');
    }
},
```

Also, ternary operator can be used as option to `if...else`

```
toggleClass: function($el, state) {
    $el.toggleClass('js-delete-session js-reset-session');
    state === 'delete' ? $el.toggleClass('fa-times fa-undo') : $el.toggleClass('fa-undo fa-times');
},
```

OR,

```
toggleClass: function($el) {
    $el.toggleClass('js-delete-session js-reset-session fa-times fa-undo');
},
```

Comment: @A1rPun Thanks, added in answer

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because it's basically the same code.

Comment: I would not recommend using the condition operator that way. You are using the expression for its side effects, and the actual purpose of the conditional expression is unused.

Comment: @Guffa Can you please explain your last comment

Comment: @Tushar: What is it in the comment that you need explained?

Comment: @Guffa About _side effect_, I never heard of it

Comment: @Tushar: The value of both the second and third operands are `$el`, so the value of the conditional expression is always the same regardless of the value of the first operand. The only difference is the additional code that is executed in the second and third operands which doesn't affect the result of the expression, but has the side effect of changing some classes.

Comment: @Tushar: IMO Guffa means the operator is generally used for assignments and not for executing any functions or methods

Answer (score 4):

As you are toggling the same classes in both states, you don't need separate code for the states. You can even put the classes in the same call:

```
toggleClass: function($el) {
  $el.toggleClass('js-delete-session js-reset-session fa-times fa-undo');
},
```

Comment: Took time to realize that they all are same classes +1